# Using .xml Filename to create sub directories

Tags: c#, date, directory

I need to create sub directories in a user defined target folder. I need to do this based on date within the filename. The filename is formatted "Result9_9_2013 1-31-13 PM.xml". I need to create a folder for every Year, Month, and Day for every instance. I am new to C# and am having issues with how to create the directories using just the "9_9_2013" portion of the filename. How would I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a `RegEx` to extract the date portion of the filename, then create the new directory from that.

Comment: Could you show us what you're currently doing and go from there?

Comment: Are you having trouble with the code or the logic?

Comment: you will use the Directory Class (System.IO) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Path to folder including folder name");  Thats how you create a directory in C#   If you require more assistance you will need to provide more info and a sample of your file, if you are reading from the file.   IF you are just reading file names and need to create directories based on that than also state that.   Code of what you have tried is also very welcomed.

Comment: I currently work with software that outputs these .xml result files in this exact format every time "Result9_9_2013 1-31-13 PM.xml". I need to loop through a user selected source directory which should have hundreds of these files. I need to read the date from each and for every one I must copy the file into its respective year/Month/day folder. Essentially it is so that we can locate these easier. I am not familiar with regex (new to C#) so I was going to use:  "string date = fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 20, 16);" after this is done I am still a litle cloudy on the logic for copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip off the "Result" prefix from your file name

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("9_9_2013 1-31-13 PM","d_M_yyyy h-mm-ss tt",     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Now you have date time and you can create you directory naming in format you wish with the reverse like this

```
String dirName = time.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Comment: this worked. but because I am mad at it now I will also have to try the regex (need the learning exp.). Thanks again.